# Permission error when auto mounting network drive Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, fstab

Error when trying to open mapped drive:

> mount: only root can mount //192.168.0.2/Music on
>   /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic

This is my latest (attempt) entry in fstab:

```
//192.168.0.2/Music /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Then created a .smbcredentials in my home folder, added the correct username and password.

> username=MYUSERNAME
>   password=MYPASSWORD

Changed my fstab entry to:

```
//192.168.0.2/Music /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic cifs credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Same error, but I can manually mount using:

```
sudo mount -a
```

this connects to the network drive. However, I have no permission to unmount, and automount still fails on system startup.

I am connecting to an Ubuntu 14.04 PC running the smb server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Before I started, open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Created a hidden text file called 'smbcredentials' text file in my home folder. Open Terminal.

```
echo >.smbcredentials
```

Change the permissions of the file to prevent unwanted access to your credentials:

```
chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
```

edit file

```
gedit ~/.smbcredentials
```

Add (this was my remote samba user account details):

```
username=msusername
password=mspassword
```

Save and close

I created a folder in my Music folder called ServerMusic. Open Terminal.
cd ~/Music

```
mkdir /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic
```

Edit fstab

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Then added:

```
//192.168.0.2/Music /home/pst007x/Music/ServerMusic cifs auto,credentials=/home/pst007x/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

where:

*pst007x is my local account name*

*//192.168.0.2/Music is my Samba share location*

Saved
Tested in terminal:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed that problem on my system by allowing me to mount a samba share without having to enter my password.

My `.profile` contains:

```
# mount my network share
HDRIVE=$HOME/HDrive
WINH="//nzch1s003/users/$USER"
SMBUSER=$USER
SMBOPTIONS="-o credentials=/home/$SMBUSER/.samba.id,uid=$SMBUSER,gid=$SMBUSER"
# create mounting points, if not there
if [ ! -d $HDRIVE ]
then
   mkdir -p $HDRIVE
fi
# mount the drive, if not already
grep $HDRIVE /etc/mtab > /dev/null || sudo mount.cifs $WINH $HDRIVE $SMBOPTIONS
```

Note that I set `uid` and `gid` to `$USER` in `$SMBOPTIONS`

To allow me to use `sudo mount.cifs` without having to enter my password, I created file `/etc/sudoers.d/mountcifs`, which contains:

```
# let me use smbmount without password
<username> <hostname>= NOPASSWD: /sbin/mount.cifs
```

Where `<username>` is your username and `<hostname>` is the name of your computer or its IP address.

this file should be automatically included by file `/etc/sudoers`. It should have a line like:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm good at spewing out misleading rubbish.  If you're trying to manually mount using the "mount" command as a normal user, yes you're going to get that error.  Use "**sudo mount**" instead of just "mount".  Otherwise, wait until you reboot your system and (assuming that your entry in fstab is acceptable) it will automatically mount it (and the init daemon's running as root, so you're guaranteed not to get *that* error!)

Comment: Yes, thanks for nothing helpful.... and I agree...  I am not trying to manually mount, that is not a problem. I am trying to MAP a share folder. Permissions in Samba on the remote PC is not the issue, unfortunately the issue is with the PC where I am trying to MAP the drive. I simply get this error and I cannot AUTO mount/map the drive.

Comment: The term "map" in Windows refers to an association with a drive letter, but doesn't have a clear meaning when you try to apply it to the Unix world.    So help me understand here...you finish editing /etc/fstab, and then you do what? Do you see the "only root can mount" error on your console after you type a command, or do you see it at boot time, or in a log file?

Comment: Ok, what I mean by MAP, is to mount a network drive to a local folder. In this case a music folder on a PC running the smb server, to be mounted on a local folder. The reason is that my music player does not see the network folder directly, so mounting a network folder to a local folder resolves this issue. I am doing something wrong somewhere, but I am having difficulty figuring it out. I am going to try setting up credentials file, etc on a different laptop tomorrow, just in case there is an issue with the laptop I am using. Thanks

Comment: Good luck.  Ping me if you want more input on it.  I will share that I have these boot-time mounts defined in my own fstab file on the PC I'm typing on:
    //192.168.214.11/temp /net/charles-w2kpgm_temp cifs _netdev,username=charles,password=mypassword,uid=charles,gid=boling,file_mode=0770 0 0
    //mythbuntu-xp/video /net/mythbuntu-xp_video cifs _netdev,username=guest,password=,uid=charles,gid=boling,file_mode=0660,dirmode=0770 0 0
the 1st with user & password specified right in fstab (low security) and the 2nd using anonymous (guest) access.